# spring for hadoop use FsShell autowired error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hadoop, spring-data, autowired

I am using spring for hadoop on spring boot based
The only document setting `FsShell` only did the need
But as this article
An error occurred
Error is:

> error is Could not autowire. No beans of 'FsShell' type found.

help me please

Answer (score 0):

i miss dependencies 
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-boot:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT') is working

but i am using compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT') this is not working